# How to send email using user-defined template in Prestashop module

Tags: php, email, prestashop

I am making prestashop module. After operation, I am going to send email using the template that I have made. So, I have made code as follow :

```
        $res = Mail::Send(
            (int) $customer[0]['id_lang'],
            'atomicseller',
            Context::getContext()->getTranslator()->trans(
                'Return label regarding order %s.',
                [$ref],
                'Emails.Subject',
                $orderLanguage->locale
            ),
            [
                '{order_ref}' => $ref,
                '{message}' => $eCont
            ],
            'Pershin.alexey@list.ru',
            'Pershin Alexey',
            'alexeygrigorev91@gmail.com',
            'Alexey Grigorev',
            null,
            null,
            _PS_MAIL_DIR_,
            true
        );
```

But the result of $res is always false. I have tried several method. In this code, all variables have correct value. I have test it. Please help me and let me know correct  method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you move the "atomicseller" template file to the active theme directory?

```
themes\your_theme_name\modules\yourmodulename\mails\en\atomicseller
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it relate with email sending?

Comment: Yes.
Your atomicseller.html and atomicseller.txt email templates files needs to be in the right folders.
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/mail/